# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() is not working

Tags: hibernate

I am having a problem utilizing the `saveOrUpdate()` method:

I have table `user`, auto generated by Hibernate:

> ```
>  ________
> |  User  |
> |________|
> |Id      |
> |Name    |
> |Address |
> |________|
> ```

I can successfully save `[Mohan, BTM]` -- creating the row `[1, Mohan, BTM]`.

However, when I update the same record in Database `[1, Mohan, EC]`, instead of updating row 1, it is creating a new row: `[2 , Mohan, EC]`

Comment: can you please show us the key lines of your code .

Answer (score 1):

It is creating new record because it has a different id, I assume like hibernate mapping is

```
<id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
```

When object has different id, it consider as new record. Above mapping will auto generate a id, When you try to update same object, then your have to explicit set object id.